# What do you mean by "This badge can be awarded multiple times"?

Tags: discussion, badges, enlightened-badge, badge-description

The Enlightened badge description says:

> First answer was accepted with at
>   least 10 up votes. This badge can be
>   awarded multiple times.

English is not my primary language so maybe I'm missing something, but I don't get it. If it's only for the first answer accepted with at least 10 up votes, how can it be awarded multiple times?

Also if it can be awarded multiple time, why do I only have 1 when I should have 2 for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798888/why-is-firebug-making-website-slow-and-how-to-fix-it/798910#798910) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289372/css-image-sprites/1289378#1289378)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've only received the badge once because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798888/why-is-firebug-making-website-slow-and-how-to-fix-it/798910#798910) wasn't the first answer to the question.  Shog9's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798888/why-is-firebug-making-website-slow-and-how-to-fix-it/798899#798899) has a date stamp of **Apr 28 at 16:56** whereas yours is **Apr 28 at 16:58**.

The Enlightened badge is awarded when the

> first answer [posted] was accepted with at least 10 up votes

It's tripped me up in the past too!

Comment: Thanks. So even if I did get the answer and the upvotes I won't get the badge? That's weird, isn't it?

Comment: No. The badge is defined so that you can get it only if you were the first one to answer the question.

Comment: I'll agree that the badge's wording is unclear. You should take that up with Jeff and a board with nails in it.

Comment: Thanks, I was way off in my understanding of that one :)

Answer (score 1):

It means you can receive the badge more than once, for different answers.

This is in contrast with badges like Editor, which you can only receive once.

You don't have the second badge because in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798888?sort=oldest#sort-top) you weren't the first answer. The shogmeister beat you by two minutes.

Comment: Makes sense. But then I don't get why I only received 1 when I should have 2. I guess it would be a different question

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is around the ambiguous term 'first' in the descirption 'First answer was accepted...'

Although `first` could refer to '**the first time** you get a 10-upvoted answer accepted,'  here it means '**the first answer in** (to be posted) to a question which turns out to be the accepted answer and is so good that it is upvoted 10 times'