# Clarify the wording for the Enlightened badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, enlightened-badge, badge-description

The wording is currently

> First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

However as demonstrated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21400/what-do-you-mean-by-this-badge-can-be-awarded-multiple-times) the wording isn't clear.  I know I've made the mistake myself. I'm sure there is a better wording out there.

Comment: I suspect it's kinda by-design to have badge descriptions worded vaguely.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you are using badges to try and encourage good behavior, it would probably help if people had a clear understanding of what the desired behavior was.

Comment: TheTXI: I'm a proponent of lucid wording in badge descriptions. In fact, I posted a suggestion for clarifying Populist on user voice at the time it was introduced. I just mentioned it's very likely to be declined.

Comment: I have to agree with that :)

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, wouldn't class this as a bug though

Comment: Is it necessary that the answer be accepted **after** it gets the upvotes? That's the only reason I can see why I wouldn't get the badge [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879219/f-is-a-real-valued-function-f-is-differentiable-at-a-point-does-that-imply/2879221#2879221).

Answer (score 19):

> You were the first to answer a
>   question. Your answer was accepted and
>   received a score of at least +10. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

This makes more sense because it stresses that you answered first, was accepted, and reached a score of +10 (the whole ten upvote thing is very confusing and is not true. 9 upvotes + 1 downvote + 1 more upvote still makes +9 and you won't get the badge).

**Edit**: Added the multiple times at the end because I forgot.

Answer (score 4):

> First answer to the question was accepted with at least 10 up votes. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: +1 a few little words make things that much more clear